# an eigenvalue problem for Jacobi Forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis

Assume $G(q,z)$ is a Jacobi form of a certain index k. It is known that $G$ can be expanded in a Taylor series with coefficients in the ring of quasi-modular forms (generators $E_2, E_4$ and $E_6$).

$\partial_{E_2}$ just means partial derivative w.r.t. $E_2$.

> **QUESTION.** Does $G$ satisfy a differential equation of the form
> $$\partial_{E_2}G=f(z) G$$
> for some function $f(z)$?

Comment: Could you clarify the definition of $\partial_{E_2}$ and specify what “suitable” means in this context?